# What is the definitively correct way to hook up a 3-prong electrical dryer cord?

Tags: electrical, dryer

I have a new dryer, and I have a 3-prong outlet (NEMA 10-30). The written instructions and the video instructions for this model contradict each other. Internet research has only confused me more. Looking for a clear, definitive answer... Do I install the wires like this (pic 1):
[image]

...where the white wire is left connected to the chassis (this is what the manufacturer video says, and what most other videos I’ve found say)

OR do I do it like this (pic 2):
[image]

...where I connect the white wire to the middle (neutral) terminal? This is what some internet things say, and this is also what the written instructions say, with an additional claim that I need an external ground wire connected to the chassis and then imaginably, a ground.

Comment: The "definitively correct way" is to run a ground wire to the socket location (which you can, without needing to follow or replace the present Hot, Hot Neutral wiring, since the 2014 code cycle IIRC) and toss that 3-wire socket in the trash and use a 4-wire cord to a 4-wire plug to a correctly wired 4-wire socket.

Comment: I have an electrician coming to do some other work on our home... is swapping a 3-prong outlet to a 4-prong outlet a huge endeavor? Does it require extensive rewiring? If not, I would just ask them to swap this out while they’re here.

Comment: I would agree with @ecnerwal but you are not required to update wiring ,, knob and tube is still code compliant with a 3 wire connection I would recommend a connection from the metal water pipe to the frame green screw totally code compliant today.

Comment: @Ed_Beal do I have to connect directly to the water pipe? It’s behind a wall currently and I’m trying to avoid a hole. Can I connect it to the metal part of the valve that’s visible?

Comment: @admbmb -- can you post a photo of the inside of the receptacle box? That'd tell us if that receptacle swap will be easy or a big deal

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t, it’s completely finished around it and I do not currently want to put holes in the wall.

Comment: @admbmb You can ask the electrician to quote for the task. Quotes are usually free, and seeing as they are there already...

Comment: Yes any part of the metal water piping system should be grounded. For many years water piping was the only ground. As long as it is I contact with earth for 10’ that would still be a code allowed grounding electrode. Because plastic plumbing is replacing metal it is not as popular as a grounding electrode but is still allowed in the 2020 code and the only way to make a 3 wire connection safe (this actually turns it into a 4 wire).

Comment: I would consider running a separate ground wire to a nearby copper water pipe (after you've verified that the copper runs uninterrupted all the way back to the underground source, which is a steel pipe, not plastic).

Comment: @admbmb -- no, you just have to turn the dryer breaker off then unfasten the dryer receptacle from the wall (don't undo the wires though!)

Comment: @HotLicks -- can't use the water pipe for this, you'd have to run back to the panel, to a grounding electrode conductor, or to a properly grounded 30A+ circuit

Comment: *"definitively correct*" as opposed to un-definitively correct ?

Comment: You don’t know but that is code. Some years back a community water system was replaced. I was called to repair a service the problem was no ground the original feed was replaced all the way to the house with plastic. It can happen but code still today in 2020 allows a pipe electrode to be one of the grounding electrodes. Years ago only one grounding electrode was required today a supplemental electrode is required so in the case where the pipe was removed you would still have 1.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to make a 3-wire connection safe.

It's only legal *on a legacy basis, with certain cable types* because the appliance industry complained and moaned that they'd lose appliance sales if it was outlawed.

What they are actually doing is connecting chassis to the live neutral.  The concept is that neutral is *supposed* to be safe... as long as there aren't any loose connections... and loose connections are unlikely since these plugs and wiring are rarely disturbed. *Uh huh.*

So it is *leeeegal* to jumper the appliance chassis to the neutral wire and then call it a day.  Would I do it? Heck no!

However in my experience many installations either have a 3-wire receptacle  *needlessly* because they *actually do* have ground behind the receptacle... or they are using a cable type that was always illegal (/2 + ground NM or UF).

You are really, really better off upgrading to 4-prong receptacle and plug ASAP.  That will give you a separate neutral and ground.

If your installation is old and uses a legal cable type (/3 noground or SE), then it's legal to **retrofit** a ground from the socket to anywhere that has a #10 or larger ground back to the panel - water heater, grounding electrode wires, any metal conduit, or back to the panel.

If it is infeasible to retrofit a ground, you can change the receptacle to 4-prong *anyway*, wire the appliance for 4-prong *anyway* (meaning: isolate neutral from ground, very important!), and then use a 2-pole GFCI breaker to feed it.  This is labeled "GFCI Protected / No Equipment Ground".

Comment: Why bother to change to a 4-wire receptacle if the circuit is GFCI with no equipment ground?

Comment: because touching a chassis on a live neutral where an asymmetric load or other significant phase fault occur, will kill you.

Comment: @batp because a 3-wire cord requires jumpering  neutral to chassis.  Bootlegging utterly defeats the protection  of the GFCI.

Comment: What about this: leave the outlet as is (3-prong), use a 3-prong dryer cord, leave the ground terminal on the dryer unconnected, and use a 2-pole gfci breaker? I believe this is what @batsplat is asking. And I don't see anything wrong with that approach.

Comment: To clarify, my question is specifically about the last paragraph ("GFCI Protected / No Equipment Ground") of your answer. And by "leave the ground terminal on the dryer unconnected", I mean connect the dryer following whatever the manual says about using a 4-wire cable, but don't connect the ground wire from the power cord (well, there isn't one).

Comment: @Haozhun -- you wire the dryer as a 4-prong dryer with a 4-prong cord, and use a 4-prong (NEMA 14) receptacle, but leave the ground terminal on the *receptacle* unconnected if you're using that plan

Comment: @Haozhun That's fine if you live on a desert island and have total control of everything.  But you can't do that in a society where different people's actions interact.  Suppose you get a better dryer, installer goes "oh ok 3-prong cord, jumper ground". *You miss it*.  You sell the house. Etc. 1000 things can happen.  It's the same basic reason they require generator interlocks and not just some smart guy knowing not to have 2 breakers on at once.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Unintentional neutral-ground jumper is bad. And I can relate to that (since I recently found and removed one in my home). @batsplat, FYI that Harper provided an answer to your (and my) question.

Answer (score 1):

You do it like in picture one. The neutral is grounded to the cabinet with the green screw.

If you had a four wire outlet, then the white wire to the cabinet would be moved to the center post like in your picture 2 and the green ground wire from your four wire plug cord would go to the cabinet with the green screw. If I were you, I'd check to see if you have four wires available in your outlet box and think about replacing the three prong cord and outlet with a four prong setup. It's a nice safety feature.

Comment: But doesn’t the connection to the chassis defeat the purpose? If current needs to be sent through that ground because of some fault (it’s actually called a neutral ground) wouldn’t that current end up on the chassis which is what I don’t want?

Comment: @admbmb No, you want the chassis grounded. if a hot  leg were to break off and hit the chassis, you want it grounded so it trips the breaker. Otherwise you end up with a hot chassis and someone touches it and turns on the water.. bye bye..

Comment: @admbmb There's no such thing as a "neutral ground".  Neutral is not ground.  In a 3-prong/wire connection, the third wire is neutral and there is no ground.  The instructions are telling you to bootleg chassis ground off neutral.  Since neutral can float up to line voltage merely from a loose connection, this is just as dangerous as it sounds.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica So this is what’s confusing. I have people telling me that I should leave that wire bonded to the chassis, and others (like you) saying that that’s dangerous. That’s what I’m trying to figure out.

Comment: @admbmb they're both right.  It's legal, but it's dangerous.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Gotcha. Another answer explained this pretty clearly as well. I will see what I can do about upgrading the outlet to 4-prong.

Comment: @admbmb As i mentioned in my answer, the four wire is the way to go but the three wire, picture 1,  is legal and the way the manufacturer stated to do it. Yes, as Harper stated, the neutral can rise to line voltage but it can also stay at zero voltage protecting you from a line fault to the cabinet.  Your question was which picture to follow for your power supply and that's picture 1.  There are thousands hooked up like this. The safety issues should be another question.

Comment: If you trace that white wire that is under the ground screw you will find it is connected to the center terminal. This"connection to the chassis" does ground the chassis to the neutral, and is done in compliance with a peculiar NEC exception to section 250.140 that allows grounding via the grounded neutral conductor in specific existing installations where a separate equipment ground wasn't required for ranges and dryers in circuits installed prior to the 1996 NEC revision cycle.

Comment: I'd be curious as to why the down vote.

Comment: @admbmb It _is_ dangerous, or at least has risks, which is why it's not permitted for new equipment. Three-prong dryer outlets like this are only allowed for historical reasons where they were already installed when they were still legal. If you don't want to do something dangerous, figure out what it would take to upgrade to a four-prong outlet.

Comment: @GlennWillen  It is permitted for new equipment but the wiring in homes has to have the four wires.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "definitive" answer, or standard hookup;  You have to follow the manufacturer's instructions but the manufacturer has dropped the ball if they have contradictory instructions out there.

That said, you will want picture two.  BUT, please make sure the spade terminal is straight and the bare metal is well clear of the terminals on the left and right, you do not want to create a short.

There is a simple principle that determines how you'll make the connections.  When 240/120V appliances are connected without the fourth equipment grounding conductor, the connections are done such that the dryer's metal frame is bonded to the neutral (white) wire.  That's what the jumper is doing.

The exact details of the connections will differ from appliance to appliance, it will depend on how the terminal block inside the dryer is wired.  In the picture below, there is a ground strap that you remove when you have four wires.

[image: three wire and four wire appliance connections]

Upgrading to a four-wire circuit would make this safer, but it's very common on older homes and not a major hazard.  Alternately adding GFCI protection to the circuit by replacing the breaker in the panel would make it safer and usually dryers are pretty GFCI compatible.

The picture is from

http://www.adamselectric.coop/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Bonding-Frames-of-Major-Appliances.pdf

where you can read a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I do not have a ground strap on my unit and my outlet is NEMA 10-30, not 10-50. Other answers indicated fairly clearly that picture 1 is the way to do it, although still not technically safe.

Comment: The "ground strap" shown in this diagram is the white wire in your dryer that is connected to the ground screw.  The picture shown for a 10-50 is functionally the same as the 30 amp 10-30 version.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease So then how do you reconcile your answer with the others? Are the others wrong?

Comment: Based on the OP's supply, it would be picture 1. Definitely.

Comment: Not sure what I am to reconcile, if the question is safety, safety is always a compromise. There are lots of things they could require that would make appliances safer. GFCI's, larger wire, built in smoke detectors, audible heat alarms, narrower fuse/breaker designations all could provide more safety.  The NFPA (the writers of the NEC) and UL consider a 3 wire safe enough to allow appliances to be sold allowing a 3 wire configuration. Some here disagree. I agree 4 wire is safer, the experts aren't requiring it at this time.

Comment: @admbmb -- can you *please* get us photos of the inside of the dryer receptacle box?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel you mean the outlet?

Comment: @admbmb -- yes, inside the outlet box

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel that may be above my skill level. I’m not sure how to approach that. I think I’ve decided to have our electrician update it to 4-prong anyway - seems to be the general consensus of everybody here.

Comment: @admbmb -- it's a matter of "turn dryer breaker off, remove the cover plate from the box,  unscrew the outlet and pull it out without unwiring it, and snap photos" -- I'm not sure where you're getting the idea that we're asking you to put holes in the wall from? Although -- if you're not comfortable with poking around in an electrical box even when it's turned off, that's fair enough...

Answer (score 0):

This is where you need to look at the MFG requirements. Notice the 2 larger wires on the outside those are normally the hots the center wire is the neutral for 3 wire without ground because the heating element is 220-240 and the motor that turns the drum is usually 120v and the controls are 120v in these cases the best option is a grounding connection from the metal water pipe to the frame of the dryer . I can say this because by the time plastic plumbing became the norm 4 wire was code.

Comment: Not sure why the down votes but connecting the chassis to a metal water pipe is recommended but all the non electricians don’t understand that. And this was the standard for decades .

Comment: I think it’s because this isn’t a direct “answer” specifically, just some additional information. While not wrong, I suspect that’s the reason.

Comment: It states where the neutral is and how to connect the ground.

Comment: The DV doesn't make sense and I got one too.....  go figure....  +1